# Did Malvo Kill the Car Salesman?

Tags: plot-explanation, fargo-tv

Near the end of the last episode of [*Fargo*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2802850/), the car salesman pleads for his life, telling Malvo that he has a little girl at home.

Does he make it?  The show doesn't explicitly show the outcome either way.

Answer (score 3):

When Lester looked out the window for Malvo after the bathroom/bear trap incident, both cars were gone. I think this implies that Malvo did let the car salesman go.

Why did he do this? Hardly out of compassion. I just think it helped illustrate the way Malvo thought. He wasn't just a bomb, leaving death and sadness wherever it happened to land, but instead a sniper that picked and chose who he wanted to kill. It was always HIS choice who died because of him.